# Why the phrase can't be searched in my Sphinx?

Tags: search, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cjk

I have installed python documentation generator-sphinx,and post a some articles in it,recently i post an article named `股票筛选器`.
Input `筛选` can get it.

[image]

Input the whole name of the article `股票筛选器` in the search bar ,why can't get it now?

[image]

I have build a sphinx project,compressed and upload it dropbox with `sample.7z`,you can download it and install it in your sphinx,to reproduce the issue.
[sample sphinx project to reproduce the issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/877owvk1d8av54k/sample.7z?dl=0)

Comment: There might be something wrong with the _search engine_ in _Sphinx_ itself. I would recommend raising the issue in the [_Sphinx_ bug tracker](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `筛选` is indexed but `股票筛选器` isn't. This happens because `股票筛选器` is recognized as three different terms/words `股票`, `筛选` and`器`.

The index exists only for these terms(single characters are ignored):
[image]

As the single characters are ignored, only would `股票` and `筛选` fetch you results.

**EDIT**

In `_static\language_data.js` append the following code snippet at the end of the file:

```
function getAllSubstrings(str) {
  var i, j, result = [];

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < str.length + 1; j++) {
          result.push(str.slice(i, j));
      }
  }
  return result.sort(function(a, b){ return a.length - b.length;});
}
```

Should look like:[image]

In `_static\searchtools.js` insert the below code snippet *above* this commented code `//console.debug('SEARCH: searching for:');`:

```
if(searchterms.length==1)
        searchterms = getAllSubstrings(searchterms[0]);
```

Should look like: [image]

Again, in `_static\searchtools.js` in the function `performTermsSearch`(this function should be around/at line 379)

1. Inside the function, look for this comment  `// add support for
   partial matches`.
2. Below the comment, you will find this `if` condition
   `word.length > 2`.
3. Change the condition to `word.length > 0`

Should look like: [image]

4. Scroll a bit down. You will find this comment `// no match but word was a required one`.
5. Remove the if condition which is directly below it.

[image]

Test it, should probably work:

[image]

Comment: Can i make the three words as a whole words?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `searchindex.js` file generated by Sphinx.

Can you inspect that file, and, to start with, make sure you have in the `terms` the value `股票筛选器` defined?

```
Search.setIndex({
    docnames: ["docs/change-log/index", "docs/dependency-injection", "docs/examples/entity-framework"],
    envversion: {
        "sphinx.domains.c": 1,
        "sphinx.domains.changeset": 1,
        "sphinx.domains.citation": 1,
        sphinx: 56
    },
    filenames: ["docs\\change-log\\index.rst", "docs\\dependency-injection.rst", "docs\\examples\\entity-framework.rst"],
    objects: {},
    objnames: {},
    objtypes: {},
    terms: {
        _dbcontext: 19,
        _filepath: 19,
        _logger: [0, 7, 10, 11, 14, 27],
        _triggerinterv: 8,
        abov: [20, 24],
        kisslog: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
        kisslogapi: 15,
        zaeffer: 24,
        zero: 24
    },
    titles: ["Change log", "Dependency injection", "Entity Framework exceptions"],
    titleterms: {
        "break": 0,
        Use: 6,
        about: 27,
        ajax: 24,
        ani: 20,
        antlr: 24,
    }
})
```